# CUDA bandwidthTest.cu

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I want to compile and run the bandwidthTest.cu in the CUDA SDK. I face the two following errors when I compile it with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 bandwidthTest.cu -o bTest

cutil_inline.h: no such file or directory
shrUtils.h: no such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use the makefile inclyded in the CUDA SDK

Answer (score 2):

Add the current directory to your include search path.

nvcc -I. -arch=sm_20 bandwidthTest.cu -o bTest

Comment: -L only changes the library search path. -I changes the include search path.

Comment: @talonmies: Oops. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the two header files you tried to #include are not available in that directory. If you use the Visual Studio IDE, you can see the red outlining.

Comment: They are in the same directory, and I don't know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Find the path to cutil_inline.h and the path to shrUtils.h and put them in the compilation line in the following way:

```
nvcc -Ipath to cutil_inline.h -Ipath to shrUtils.h -arch=sm_20 bandwidthTest.cu -o bTest
```

Also, consider using a makefile for the compilation in case you aren't.